# How to handle nginx reverse proxy with return URL

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have a third party application, call it 3partyapp that does a returnurl, for example if I enter in the browser

```
example.com/3partyapp
```

it will respond with

```
example.com/3partyapp/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f3partyapp
```

That all works, now I want to put it behind an nginx reverse proxy.

On the nginx box, when I do a

```
curl -i 10.17.1.6/3partyapp/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f3partyapp
```

it works (I get http 200), the nginx box and the 3partyapp server is on the same network and 10.17.1.6 is the private ip of the 3partyapp.

If I do a

```
curl -i 10.17.1.6/3partyapp
```

I get 302

Here’s my nginx location block

```
    location /3partyapp {
        proxy_set_header        Host                            $host ;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server              $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For                 $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass              http://10.17.1.6/3partyapp;
        proxy_pass_header       Set-Cookie;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_cookie_path / "/; HTTPOnly;  Secure";
        autoindex off;
   }
```

With this setup, in a browser, I type in

```
example.com/3partyapp
```

I get a 404 with

```
https://example.com/3partyapp/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f3partyapp
```

I think I need a proxy_rewrite but have not been successful, any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What `Location` header do you get for HTTP 302 response with `curl -i 10.17.1.6/3partyapp`?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /3partyapp/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f3partyapp
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 29 Aug 2021 23:44:26 GMT
Content-Length: 164

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="3partyapp/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f3partyapp">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help you. Put this in your nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    
    location /3partyapp/ {
      proxy_pass http://10.17.1.6/3partyapp/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f3partyapp;         
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but same behaviour as what I had

Comment: @munchine please try the edited solution. Here I have assumed that example.com is served via port 80. Otherwise you have to put the relevant port there